# Matplotlib lines do not join smoothly, Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using matplotlib to draw the outline of a cylindrical body, however the lines do not want to join up smoothly, as seen in the range x[40,60].

[image]

It is really subtle in this image I know, but it is unfortunately not acceptable for my purposes. I hope it is visible for you to see.

Using more data points does not seem to make a difference.

Is there a way to get curved lines to join up more smoothly in matplotlib?

Original code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

length = 100.
a = 40
b = 20
n = 2.
alpha = np.radians(25.)
d = 18.

x_nose = np.linspace(0,a,1000)
r_nose = (0.5*d*(1 - ((x_nose-a)/a)**2)**(1/n))

x_mid = np.linspace(x_nose[-1],a+b,2)
r_mid = np.array([r_nose[-1],r_nose[-1]])

x_tail = np.linspace(x_mid[-1],length,1000)
l_tail = length-a-b
r_tail = (0.5*d - ((3*d)/(2*l_tail**2) - np.tan(alpha)/l_tail)*(x_tail-a-b)**2 + (d/l_tail**3 - np.tan(alpha)/l_tail**2)*(x_tail-a-b)**3)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_nose,r_nose,'k',linewidth=2,antialiased=True)
plt.plot(x_mid,r_mid,'k',linewidth=2,antialiased=True)
plt.plot(x_tail,r_tail,'k',linewidth=2,antialiased=True)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

You can see the effect more easily when zoomed in:

[image]

Comment: This looks a bit like a rounding error in the original calculation. Can you provide the code you're using to generate the line?

Comment: I added the code. You will see the shape is divided into 3 segments and I use the last entry of the previous segment as the starting point for the next segment, that is why I think the lines should join smoothly.

Comment: It could be that the antialiasing is making the "nose" and "tail" curves look thicker than they are, while the "mid" section is horizontal and therefore doesn't need antialiasing.  Just a guess...

Comment: It looks slightly worse without antialiasing, I put it in to try and improve it.

Comment: Yes, on closer inspection, this doesn't seem to be the problem.  I've added a zoomed-in version of your image to the question to better illustrate it.

Comment: Thank you. I should have done that.

Comment: Can you add the full code example (including the parameters e.g. values for `a` `b` etc.)?

Comment: What does `length` do here? What's it value?

Comment: I updated the code so that it can run as is. The length var is the total length of the body.

Comment: There is a `snap` property which might be catching you out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but you may be able to mitigate by constructing a single `x` and `r` array with the full line to draw.

```
x = np.append(x_nose, x_mid)
x = np.append(x, x_tail )
r = np.append(r_nose, r_mid)
r = np.append(r, r_tail )

plt.plot(x,r,'k',linewidth=2,antialiased=True)
```

This obviously prevents you altering line styles of individual elements, but it looks like you don't want to do that. This works for me:

[image: Plot showing the effect of appending the x and r arrays]

Comment: Ah brilliant, an elegant solution. Thank you!